# mode.save() create only one file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

i read the documentation of model.save(). it says that it creates the folder but when i save it it just create a single file. when i use this file to change the code from keras to tensorflow-lite it gives this error:

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: C:\Users\Munib\New folder\3_layer_model_try3/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

i am also uploading the picture of the file and its location.[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you swap from using blackslashes to forwardslashes in the path specification? Ie. should your path instead be ```C:\Users\Munib\New folder\3_layer_model_try3\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}```?

Comment: @jwalton Sir, this is the error i got my file name is new_model now i mistakenly post the error of previous file the location of the file is : ```C:\Users\Munib\New folder ```. The error i got is: ```OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: C:\Users\Munib\New folder\my_model.pb/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

Comment: And Sir, can you please tell me why my model.save() creates only one file while on internet it says that it creates folder which contains files

Comment: Sir,  the code is: ```import tensorflow as tf
# Converting a SavedModel to a TensorFlow Lite model.
saved_model_dir = r"C:\Users\Munib\New folder"
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the model you saved is a `keras model` and not 'SavedModel`. So, you need to use`from_keras_model` as shown below.

I tried to simulate the issue by using simple model and was successfully reproduced your issue. check below fro the code.

```
!pip install tf-nightly
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

After training the model, i guess you saved it as follows

```
model.save('my_model.h5',save_format='h5')
```

Then tried, to convert the model to tflite model (following is your code)

```
# Converting a SavedModel to a TensorFlow Lite model. 
saved_model_dir = '/content/my_model.h5' #r"C:\Users\Munib\New folder" 
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

With the above code I got the following error (looks like same error as you are facing)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a9a46a590f90> in <module>()
      1 # Converting a SavedModel to a TensorFlow Lite model.
      2 saved_model_dir = '/content/my_model.h5' #r"C:\Users\Munib\New folder"
----> 3 converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
      4 tflite_model = converter.convert()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py in parse_saved_model(export_dir)
    111                   (export_dir,
    112                    constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PBTXT,
--> 113                    constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB))
    114 
    115 

OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /content/my_model.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

## Here is the updated code that works

```
# Converting a SavedModel to a TensorFlow Lite model. 
saved_model_dir = '/content/my_model.h5' #r"C:\Users\Munib\New folder" 
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(saved_model_dir)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(loaded_model)# .from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/tflite_simple_floatmodel.ipynb).

Comment: Thank you so much sir its working now. Can you help me a little more i am new to machine learning

Comment: I will help you. But, please post your questions to community so that If I am not able to answer quickly, then someone from the community will answer and you can move on faster in your learning.

Comment: Ok Sir, is this model in freeze condition now or is there any way i can check the model?

Comment: When you run the code, you can see "converted_model.tflite" file written to local directory. You can use https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/ to visualiize your model.

Comment: Thank you sir its showing almost similar but i a bit different from the keras model. Sir i am posting the pictures in my answer so you can help me understand it.